# Switch case help in C

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

I am in 9th class so still a beginner in C. Can anyone tell how to do this? When anybody enters value more than 4 then it should print 'default:' label of switch case statement. I tried using do while for that but it gave errors. The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void main()
{
   int n1,n2,a=0,c,r,o;
S:
   printf("\n \n 1. Addition \n 2. Substract \n 3. Multiply \n 4. Divide \n \n");
   printf("\n Enter your choice: \t");
   scanf("%d",&o);
   printf("Enter two numbers: \t");
   scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);

   switch (o)
   {
      case 1:
         a=n1+n2;
         printf("\n Please wait..");
         sleep(1);
         printf("\n Answer is %d",a);
         printf("\n Perform another action too? 1 for Yes and 0 for No \t",c);
         scanf("%d",&c);
         if (c==1)
         {
            goto S;
         }
         if (c==0)
         {
            printf("\n \n \n Bye!");
         }
         else
         {
            printf("Choice ain't correct!");
         }
L:
         printf("\n \n Restart loop? 1 for Yes and any other number for No \t",r);
         scanf("%d",&r);
         if (r==1)
         {
            printf("\n \n Restarting Loop..");
            sleep(1);
            goto S;
         }
        else
        {
           printf("\n \t \t \t Bye!");
           goto L;
        }
        break;

      case 2:
        a=n1-n2;
        printf("\n Please wait..");
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n Answer is %d",a);
        printf("\n Perform another action too? 1 for Yes and 0 for No \t",c);
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if (c==1)
        {
           goto S;
        }
        if (c==0)
        {
           printf("\n \n \n Bye!");
        }
        else
        {
           printf("Choice ain't correct!");
        }
M:
        printf("\n \n Restart loop? 1 for Yes and any other number for No \t",r);
        scanf("%d",&r);
        if (r==1)
        {
           printf("\n \n Restarting Loop..");
           sleep(1);
           goto S;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("\n \t \t \t Bye!");
           goto M;
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        a=n1*n2;
        printf("\n Please wait..");
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n Answer is %d",a);
        printf("\n Perform another action too? 1 for Yes and 0 for No \t",c);
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if (c==1)
        {
           goto S;
        }
        if (c==0)
        {
           printf("\n \n \n Bye!");
        }
        else
        {
           printf("Choice ain't correct!");
        }
  N:
        printf("\n \n Restart loop? 1 for Yes and any other number for No \t",r);
        scanf("%d",&r);
        if (r==1)
        {
           printf("\n \n Restarting Loop..");
           sleep(1);
           goto S;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("\n \t \t \t Bye!");
           goto N;
        }
        break;

      case 4:
        a=n1/n2;
        printf("\n Please wait..");
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n Answer is %d",a);
        printf("\n Perform another action too? 1 for Yes and 0 for No \t",c);
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if (c==1)
        {
           goto S;
        }
        if (c==0)
        {
           printf("\n \n \n Bye!");
        }
        else
        {
           printf("Choice ain't correct!");
        }
O:
        printf("\n \n Restart loop? 1 for Yes and any other number for No \t",r);
        scanf("%d",&r);
        if (r==1)
        {
           printf("\n \n Restarting Loop..");
           sleep(1);
           goto S;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("\n \t \t \t Bye!");
           goto O;
           break;
      default:
              printf("Choice ain't correct");
              break;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! 2 tips : 1)You should indent your code to make it more readable. 2) `goto` is evil.

Comment: I'm an advocacy of goto statements, but this is the perfect example code how to not use goto's and the reason why they are frowned upon.

Comment: @ Arnaud Denoyelle thats a lie, goto is evil if you aren't able to respect the standard. But then each language cosntruct may be evil.

Comment: Where you have case 0;? Are you missing a case directive somewhere?

Comment: @Zaibis gotos *easily* become evil, as you can see here.

Comment: I did my best on improving the indentation but still I am not sure it is readable.

Comment: Elazar Then how can I use anything else like goto in my code?

Hagubear But the program is giving correct output.

Comment: More important than spaces and goto: what error do you get?

Comment: Don't define `default` action inside `else`, its compile error.

Comment: DRY - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself in particular, extract Y/N questions to a function. also, you can merge of the body of each case into a single function..

Comment: @Jason Park One of the reason why this code is incorrect is that it is hard to read. As you are a beginner in C, do you know that you can extract some parts of code into methods apart? It would help you to split it into small understandable pieces of code.

Comment: @Elazar The point is he calls him self a beginner. I also have seen beginners writing `if(/*...*/);{return 0;}/*more code*/` so the `if` is also evil?;) I understand you point of view, but just saying its evil, is not ok, if you know what you are doing and know when a goto is the best idea it is ok. but most people don't know and the result is code like this. but nevermind our discussion is Off-topic to OP.

Comment: When I used do while for default: label then it gave error: "Label Identifier Excepted"
but without do while, its getting complied & running..

Comment: what can I use instead of goto performing the same func if its evil???

Comment: @Jason Park another hitn to you as beginner: never change code to soemthing you dont understand, just because the compiler THEN accepts it. you HAVE to be sure whats happening in each line what the commands do, toherwise the programm won't work for sure ;)

Comment: You can extract pieces of codes in methods apart. this is the cleanest way imho.

Comment: @Jason Park and before you write code, you should think about how to write it in a constant flow. if this is hard for you, you should google "Nassi–Shneiderman diagram" and try to put your code in this form. this is the way how i learned to code in a interuptless flow.

Comment: @Elazar I agree with Zaibis. `Goto` is a tool. It's difficult to use, but often  it should NOT be avoided. Linux kernel can give you many many great examples of error handling without bloating the code just to avoid `goto`. We know that high voltage can kill you, but we do not tell people around that electricity is evil. It's dangerous, but it should be used when it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is really bad, reasons stated in the comments at your post; But I think you should learn by improving your own code, that's what helped in my early days:

1. You should check the first input (with your switch) BEFORE you ask the user to enter two values. That's program logic
2. In default-case, add a goto O; or even goto S;

   default:
   printf("Choice ain't correct. Try again..\n");
   goto O;
   break;
3. You may want to terminate program after you said bye - would be more reasonable to me
4. I really really really recommend to refactor the code to run without go-to's. Its a really nice assignment to solve with a single loop around it.

What errors in particular do you mean?

~ edit ~

I think I'll illustrate what I mean with some code, that's how simple your program is, hope that helps a little and you don't just copy the code but try to understand why that's "better" (at least shorter and a bit easier to maintain and read) than your's ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    int n1,n2,a=0,c,o;

    int terminate = 0;

    while(!terminate)
    {
        printf("\n \n 1. Addition \n 2. Substract \n 3. Multiply \n 4. Divide \n \n");
        printf("\n Enter your choice: \t");
        scanf("%d",&o);

        if(o < 0 || o> 4)
        {
             printf("Choice ain't correct!\n");
             continue; // restarts loop
        }

        printf("Enter two numbers: \n ");
        scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);

        switch(o)
        {
            case 1: a = n1 + n2;
                break;

            case 2: a = n1-n2;
                break;

            case 3: a = n1*n2;
                break;

            case 4: a = n1/n2;
                break;

            default:
                // never reached, since validation of o was done before switch
                break;
        }

        sleep(1);
        printf("\n Answer is %d",a);



        printf("\n Perform another action too? 1 for Yes and 0 for No \t",c);
        scanf("%d",&c);

        if (c!=1)
        {
            terminate = 1; // this causes the loop to terminate
        }
    }

    printf("\n \n \n Bye!");

}
```

Comment: Encouraging the use of goto is not helpful, in my opinion. Yes, it has its place, but its place is definitely not in a beginner's program.

Comment: That's why I added the code sample, I still remember when I was at this stage (I was 14 back then). What we're told "Hey, there's something like goto, but don't use it, its more a relict from assembler language than really designed for c-programming". In assembler it makes sense, in C it does not really (in my opinion).
Jason, unfortunately I'm pretty busy at the moment so not really time to help you out, but I'm pretty sure you get it done on your own. I always learned the most when I figured out on myself (tough this takes a lot of time..). Otherwise probably just ask your mates or teachers?

Answer (score 0):

My solution using while loop:

```
int main(){
    int o, a1, a2;
    printf("Hi!\r\n");
    while(1){
        printf("1234 - operations, else - exit\r\n");
        scanf("%d", &o);
        if(o < 1 || o > 4)
            break; /* breaks infinite while loop and goes straight to "bye!" */
        printf("Enter args: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &a1, &a2);
        switch(o){
        /* here your switchcase statements without default
        just make opearions and output result */
        }
    }
    printf("Bye!\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Goto operator is dangerous, not out of law, but you must use it wisely.
Try to build program using loops and if(){}else{} branches first.

Answer (score 0):

In the default case the braces are not in the right place

```
        if (r==1)
        {
           printf("\n \n Restarting Loop..");
           sleep(1);
           goto S;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("\n \t \t \t Bye!");
           goto O;
           break;
        }  // <------------------------------------------------------- Need this

      default:
        {   // <-----------------------------------------------------  Need this
              printf("Choice ain't correct");
              break;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a closing brace immediately before your default: case, that's why it's not executing.

Comment: The comment was not precise. He probably meant move default out of the else clause. So if you add a closing brace before default, you have to remove the one after default. Though i would still argue it does not achieve what was asked in the question in first place. You really need to test your first input BEFORE asking input for the next two numbers.

Comment: The comment was perfectly precise. He asked why his `default:` case is not executing, and that's why. The fact that his code contains other errors is, or should be, the subject of another question.